# How do you set cookies on frontend from the backend?

Tags: http, cookies

I'm a little confused about how to handle cookies between frontend and backend.

I have a

1. **frontend react application**
2. **a backend node express application**.

The frontend is hosted on Netlify and the backend on Heroku.

It seems that you cannot put these apps on the same domain- `www.mydomain.com` (not sure if correct). So instead I have them on different subdomains: the frontend Netlify app on **staging**.mydomain.com and the Heroku backend on **api**.mydomain.com.

But I need **api**.mydomain.com to send a locale cookie to frontend which needs to be read by javascript of the frontend app. But it seems it's not possible to set a cookie from one domain onto another- like **api**.mydomain.com to set a cookie on **staging**.mydomain.com (not sure if correct). And it seems if the cookie is on a different domain like **api**.mydomain.com, it cannot be read by javascript by the frontend app on the other domain **staging**.mydomain.com (not sure if correct).

It seems like sending cookies from a backend to frontend in order to be read by javascript would be a common behavior, so I feel I'm missing some information. Is it incorrect to have your backend and frontend on different subdomains? It didn't look like it was an option to put them on the same domain with heroku and netlify, so it seemed to me putting your backend and frontend on different subdomains was the only or atleast more common way to go. How do you handle your backend sending cookies to the frontend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was wrong that you couldn't set cookies between subdomains. Setting     the domain on the set cookie header to `mydomain.com` solved the issue.

```
    res.cookie('locale', JSON.stringify(localeObj), {
      maxAge: new Date() * 0.001 + 300,
      domain: 'mydomain.com',
      secure: true,
      sameSite:'none',
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Define where cookies are sent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent):

> **Domain attribute**
>
> The Domain attribute specifies which hosts are allowed to receive the cookie. If unspecified, it defaults to the same host that set the cookie, excluding subdomains. *If Domain is specified, then subdomains are always included.* Therefore, specifying Domain is less restrictive than omitting it. However, it can be helpful when subdomains need to share information about a user.
>
> For example, if `Domain=mozilla.org` is set, then cookies are available on subdomains like `developer.mozilla.org`.

So, yes, one needs to specify a domain.

Comment: Is this typical practice for sharing cookies between the frontend and backend using a common base domain? Or should it be avoided?